# Display TD as bock inconsistency

Tags: html, css, html-table, jsfiddle, jsbin

I am testing layouts (for HTML emails) on mobile devices.

The issue I have come across is that the code for making a table `<td>` display as block is not working in some email clients. And when I test in JSBIN and JSFiddle I get different results in the same browser!

Could someone help explain why the `<td>` displays correctly as block [here in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkk2w68b/2/) but does not [here in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yupuleqivo/1/edit?html,output)?

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width:800px){            
  table {
      width: 100% !important;
      border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  table td {
      background: #aaa;
      display: block !important;
      width: auto !important;
  }
}    
</style>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" border="0" width="100%">         
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#f0f0f0">
            ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC                                             
        </td>                                       
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#f0f0f0">
             CDE CDE CDE CDE CDE
        </td>       
    </tr>
</table>
```

Result in jsFiddle (`display: block` works):

[image: jsFiddle screenshot]

Result in jsBin (`display: block` fails):

[image: jsBin screenshot]

Comment: could you please explain the issue you are facing.. i couldn’t understand clearly.

Comment: Sorry, my original link to JSBIN was old code. I updated it and added another screenshot showing the differences I am seeing. Should make more sense now I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the jsBin fixed it.